# How to make an action on second click?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I asked a similar question earlier, and one answer said to use this:

```
var clickCounter=0;
input.onclick=function() {
 clickCounter++;
    if (clickCounter==2) {
     window.alert("Hello");
    }
   };
```

But that does not work here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <body>
  <script>
   var clickCounter=0;
   input.onclick=function() {
    clickCounter++;
    if (clickCounter==2) {
     window.alert("Hello");
    }
   };
  </script>
  <input id="testing" type="button" value="X" onClick="value='Clear'" style="border-radius: 10px; transition: 5s;">
 </body>
</html>
```

I am trying to make the notification clear on the iPhone.

Comment: Look at your console for errors and go from there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't defined what `input` is, it has to be a reference to an element. Also you need to run the code after the element has come into existance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>page title</title>
  <script>
   var clickCounter=0;
   window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById("testing").onclick = function() {
     clickCounter++;
     if (clickCounter==2) {
      window.alert("Hello");
     }
    };
   }
  </script>
 </head
 <body>
  <input id="testing" type="button" value="X" style="border-radius: 10px; transition: 5s;">
 </body>
</html>
```

A script normally goes into the `head` tag, and there should also be a `title` to be a valid HTML document.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to define the variable "input".

In pure javascript, you can use `getElementById()`:

```
var input=document.getElementById('testing');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/S9wQ2/

### Edit:

As mentioned by Steve (and Guffa), wrap your javascript in an `onload` event so that the DOM loads before your Javascript executes, like this:

```
window.onload=function() {

    var input = document.getElementById('testing');
    var clickCounter = 0;
    input.onclick = function () {
        clickCounter++;
        if (clickCounter == 2) {
            window.alert("Hello");
        }
    };

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/S9wQ2/2/

Comment: +1 - But you should mention that he needs to move his script AFTER the `input` element or it will not work (or alternatively wrap his JS in an `onload` function).

Answer (score 0):

[jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/8SBh6/)

HTML:

```
<button id="Button1">Button</button>
```

JS:

```
var clickCounter=0;
var button1 = document.getElementById('Button1')
button1.onclick=function() {
  clickCounter++;
  if (clickCounter==2) {
    window.alert("Hello");
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a native [double click event](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_ondblclick.asp) by the way:

```
document.getElementById("testing").ondblclick=function() {
     window.alert("Hello");
};
```

[Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/S9wQ2/1/)